# Is there a name for this construction of plane graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, planar-graphs

Let $G$ be a plane graph. Let $G'$ be a supergraph of $G$ obtained by inserting a face vertex in each face of $G$ and connecting the face vertex to all vertices on the boundary of the face.

For example, let $G$ be the left graph of the following picture.  $G'$ is on the right. We mark the newly added vertices and edges in pink. Does the resulting planar graph from above construction have a nice name like the dual graph?

[image]

Comment: It's analogous to _barycentric subdivision_.

Comment: It seems related to Apollonian Networks: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_network

Comment: @dbal yes. When $G$ is a triangulation, $G’$ is an Apollonian.